# Passing null as a param for replace() in javascript behaving weird?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, null

I have the follwing jQuery:

```
        $("#textArea").keyup(function(){
            var textAreaValue = $("textArea");
            if(!textArea.value.indexOf("some string")){
                textArea.value = textArea.value.replace("some string",null);
                alert("It was there!");
            }
        });
```

- Is it normal for `element.value.replace("some string",null);` to replace `"some string"` with `"null"`as a string?  And if normal can you please explain why?
- I have tested it with `element.value.replace("some string","")`, and that works fine, so what would be the difference between `null` and `""`?

*Using FireFox 3.6.3, Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like null has been type-casted to a String.

Try:

```
"a" + null // "anull"
```

Although you can't call toString() on a `null` object, it seems the null object is implicitly being converted to a String, which gives the string `"null"`.

```
String(null) // "null"
```

Comment: Passing `null` when a string is expected will not always have this result, and it is usually not a desired result anyway.

Comment: @tehMick - the behavior for String.prototype.replace as per [ECMAScript 5th ed.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) suggest that a null `replaceValue` should be replaced with the string `"null"`. It may be unexpected for other cases, but for String.prototype.replace, it's very much expected.

Comment: Good call - "Otherwise, let newstring denote the result of converting replaceValue to a String."  This may work for 5th ed. and this particular function, but then again, why pass `null` instead of `"null"` unless you're playing code golf?  It serves only to confuse future readers of you code, since a naive interpretation would be that you are replacing matches with *nothing* rather than "null".

Comment: @tehMich - I agree with you. It's extremely unintuitive to use the `null` type as a sneaky replacement for the string `"null"`. The obvious interpretation to this, as you said, is that the matching text is being removed rather than replaced.

Answer (score 1):

`""` is an empty string..

`null` is something that indicates a deliberate non-value or undefined...

`null` is mostly used to initialize `objects`

and in str.replace(param1,param2), param1 and param2 should be a `string` or something that produces a `string` ( in param2 )... in that said,

```
var heart_type = 'images/unheart.png';
alert( heart_type.replace(".png",null));​
```

will alert `images/unheartnull`.. because null was treated as a `string`...

[`.replace()` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace)

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `String.replace` is a required parameter, and it must be a string.  See [mdc](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace) and [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).  It's not normal or safe to pass `null`, which is not a string.  Don't be surprised if your code does not execute properly in all javascript engines.